# I need to update a table with a certain condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

i have a problem with some logic operation to do in PL/SQL.

Basically i have a table:

```
|DOMAIN|SECOND_NAME|SOME_VALUES|
|   X  |     XX    |28309128312|
|   X  |     XX    |11121309011|
|   Y  |     YY    |55583202300|
|   Z  |     ZZ    |00000912323|
```

and actually my table have the DOMAIN column valorized for every row but the SECOND_NAME row not valorized. Now i need to update that row in a certain method. I have those value in an excel because the name in that excel is like an alias.
I am writing in a file every alias that I found, and i will just use a DUAL to update that with a cursor->for->loop.

The problem is: In the file I am writing with the Alias have only 1 occurrence:

```
xx
yy
zz
vv
bb
nn
mm
```

table_example:
 up there where i have 2 domain with the same type X and of course the SECOND_NAME is equal for both.

If i have a dual with only one Alias and only 1 occurrence, how can i update with a cursor every record but if the DOMAIN is the same i need to valorized with the same SECOND_NAME that i used before ?

i can't have a situation like this:

```
|DOMAIN|SECOND_NAME|SOME_VALUES|
|   X  |     XX    |28309128312|
|   X  |     CC    |11121309011|   <----- error IT MUST BE 'XX'
|   Y  |     YY    |55583202300|
|   Z  |     ZZ    |00000912323|
```

Comment: Please, could you post your code?

Comment: i do not have a code, i am trying to think a code.

Comment: Sorry but you must make an attempt.  SO is not a coding service but we'd love to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `second_name` to the same value for every `domain`, you can do:

```
update t
    set second_name = (select min(t2.second_name) from t t2 where t2.domain = t.domain)
    where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.domain = t.domain);
```

I am not sure what the data in Excel has to do with this problem.

You have a problem with your data model if these columns need to be the same.  I think you need a `domains` table where the `second_name` is defined only once.

Comment: That table contains the same DOMAINS for different case, so the second name that in the file has been wrote only 1 time, has to be inserted everytime the DOMAINS is the same:
If I insert the second_name "ElectricCase" because the domain is "fftr_Elec_case", in case the next domain in list is the same it has to insert "ElectricCase" again. but on the excel is written only once